# Annotation or Markup Tool for SharePoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, markup

Is there any OOTB or third party tool that we can integrate with SharePoint On-Premises for annotation of MS Office and PDF files?

We are looking for a detailed tool to provide annotation functionalities. We are using SharePoint Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no such tools intergrated with SharePoint.

We suggest you provide your feedback in [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/).

UserVoice is the best way to give the feedback to Product Group as it’s actively monitored by them and many new features have been implemented from customers feedback.

Thanks for understanding.